# Understanding of counting and conditional probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Three integers are chosen out of the first twenty positive integers.  Find the following probabilities.  We can observe the following:
>
> - even+even+even=even
> - even+even+odd=odd
> - even+odd+odd=even
> - odd+odd+odd=odd
>
> a) P(for sum to be even)

$$\newcommand{\Choose}[2]{{^{#1}{\rm C}_{#2}}}
\frac{\Choose{10}3+\Choose{10}{1}\cdot \Choose{10}{2}}{\Choose{20}{3}}$$

The reason for this is that there are ten even numbers, and the first combination represents choosing three of them.  The next combination involves choosing one even and two odds.

> b) P(for product to be even)

The first observation I made here is that as long as we have an even number in the pile then the product has to be even.

$$\frac{\Choose{10}3+\Choose{10}2\cdot\Choose{10}1+\Choose{10}1\cdot\Choose{10}2}{\Choose{20}3}$$

This should account for the three different arrangements that involve an even number in them.

Can you verify if my understanding is correct, or lacking?

Answer (score 0):

$\color{green}\checkmark$  Yes.   If the choices are unbiased and *you are drawing without repetition*, then your reasoning is sound and the combinations you used do correctly count the favoured and total space of selection.